# Divisors: function composition with multiplication by n map on elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Washington's Weil pairing proof gives a divisor in section 11.2
$$\textrm{div}(f) = n[T] - n[\infty]$$
But then he says let $f \circ n$ denote applying the multiplication by n map, then applying f. Obviously the zeroes of this function will be all $T' : nT' = T$, like this:
$$\textrm{div}(f \circ n) = n \left( \sum_{T' : nT' = T} [T'] \right) - n \left( \sum_{R \in E[n]} [R] \right)$$
I've searched everywhere but cannot find an answer why the order of these points are n.
The book simply says that it follows from the previous equation, and [other proofs](https://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2009/03/26/the-weil-pairing/) of the weil pairing are similarly vague.

Why is the order of the points equal to n? How do they get from $\textrm{div}(f)$ to $\textrm{div}(f \circ n)$?

For example why is $\textrm{ord}_{T'}(f \circ n) = n$? How do think about the order of multiplication by n, and how that affects f?

Comment: What do you mean by "why the order of these points are $n$"? Are you asking why the divisor $n \left( \sum_{T' : nT' = T} [T'] \right) - n \left( \sum_{R \in E[n]} [R] \right)$ sums to $\infty$? As for how they got the divisor of $\operatorname{div}(f \circ n)$, you seem to be on the right track. $f$ has a unique zero at $T$ and a unique pole at $\infty$, both of order $n$. The zeroes of $f \circ n$ are as you say, and the poles are the points $R$ such that $nR = \infty$, which are exactly the $n$-torsion points.

Comment: No, I understand why it sums to $\infty$ and why those are the zeroes/poles of $f \circ n$. My question is this: why is $\textrm{ord}_{T'}(f \circ n) = n$? How does composing f with n (multiplication by n map) change the divisor? Why are the coefficients n?

Comment: I see, you want to know why the zeroes and poles are still of order $n$ after composing with the multiplication by $n$ map. Have you seen ramification indices before? This basically follows from the fact that ramification indices are multiplicative with respect to composition. $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $T$, multiplication by $n$ has ramification index $1$ at $T'$ (it has degree $n^2$ and there are $n^2$ distinct preimages of $T$), so their composition has ramification index $n \cdot 1 = n$. This is Proposition II.2.6(c) in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* if you have that book.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is greatly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the zeroes and poles of $f \circ [n]$ have the same orders as those of $f$ follows from the facts that: (i) ramification index is multiplicative with respect to composition; and (ii) $[n]$ has ramification index $1$ at each of these points $T'$.

Recall that, given a nonconstant morphism $\varphi: C_1 \to C_2$ of smooth curves and a point $P \in C_1$, the ramification index $e_\varphi(P)$ of $\varphi$ at $P$ is
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}
e_\varphi(P) := \ord_P(\varphi^* t)
$$
where $t$ is a local uniformizer at $\varphi(P)$. In the case where $f: C \to \mathbb{P}^1$, $f(P) = 0$, and $t$ is the usual affine coordinate on $\mathbb{P}^1$ at $0$, then $f^* t$ is just $f$ itself, so
$$
e_f(P) = \ord_P(f^* t) = \ord_P(f)
$$
is the order of vanishing of $f$ at $P$.

The two facts above are given in Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* Proposition II.2.6, parts (a) and (c):

**Proposition**. Let $\varphi: C_1 \to C_2$ be a nonconstant morphism of smooth curves.

(a) For every $Q \in C_2$,
$$
\sum_{P \in \varphi^{-1}(Q)} e_\varphi(P) = \deg(\varphi).
$$

(c) Given another nonconstant map $\psi: C_2 \to C_3$ of smooth curves, then for all $P \in C_1$, we have
$$
e_{\psi \circ \varphi}(P) = e_\varphi(P) e_\psi(\varphi(P)) \, .
$$

Assuming $n$ is relatively prime to the characteristic of the base field $K$, there are $n^2$ distinct points $T'$ such that $[n]T' = T$ over $\overline{K}$. Since $[n]$ has degree $n^2$, then $e_{[n]}(T') = 1$ for every such $T'$ by part (a). Now applying part (c), we have
\begin{align*}
e_{f \circ [n]}(T') = e_{[n]}(T') e_{f}(T) = 1 \cdot n = n \, .
\end{align*}